# mongo is slow for 20m record. how optimise?

Tags: mongodb

I read a lot good things about mongodb and decide to implement it in my organisation. My pilot was to move one sql server view to mongodb. The number of records is 20 milions. I simply copy the data(mssql->mongodb) by my program and I program my UI to query mongodb with up to 7 filters that can be used or not. I didn't add indexes and neither did any optimization activity. 
When I execute my query even with 2 filter(dates range) it needs more then 5 minutes to return me that 100 documents that corresponds to the query. First minute server's memory is normal, but then it goes to 100% utilization and even after the query is finished it remains like this. Can you explain such behavior? what should I do next? 
As I know its possible to apply index only for one column, and as my query contains dynamic filters for 7 fields will it be effective to create some indexes.
Is mongodb in general faster then mssql for such tasks, or I am wrong in chosing the approach to solve the task

Comment: add indexes and read the documentation http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/indexes/

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely look at indexes as suggested by @xlembouras but also look at sharding: 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/

If your data is distributed across nodes with proper shard key then you will notice major performance improvement.

If you are putting dumping your data into a single node and not backing it up with indexes or sharding then you will not see any major performance improvement w.r.t MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to build indexes. Look at your query patterns to determine what indexes you'll need to build. Your queries are slow because it is likely scanning all 20M documents to find the results. Not good.

Second, the number of docs doesn't matter as much as the data set size, more specifically, the size of your working set. You want to ensure your working set + indexes fit into RAM. If they don't you'll find mongo scanning from disc, which is slow.

Third, you can look into sharding (only after looking at options above). It is important to note, you shouldn't always shard your collections and, in some cases, sharding can be prohibitive given your requirements. Sharding adds complexity to your architecture. You need to read the documentation thoroughly to understand if sharding is the correct course of action for your environment.